# Convert a password protected Excel file to CSV without Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a number of password protected Excel 2013 files that I know the password for. Is it possible to convert them to CSV in batch and without Excel?

I have looked into Docrecrypt but I do not have the required certificate set up to remove the password from the file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Powershell. Look at these articles, as they should provide all the information you need. 1. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2007/04/12/how-can-i-remove-the-password-when-opening-an-excel-spreadsheet/ 2. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3223/extract-and-convert-all-excel-worksheets-into-csv-files-using-powershell/

Comment: Hi @Keltari thank you for those links, unfortunately they both require Excel to be installed which is not possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

1) Remove the passwords first in batch. I couldn't get DocRecrypt to work either.

2) Use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) to using [command line parameters](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/) to save it as CSV using a parameter such as `--convert-to csv`